# React Promise is not awaited

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have an input of type image which accepts multiple images. I save this in a React Hook and want to upload it to my Firebase Storage after the user presses Upload.
For this I use a promise and an async method. Once the array of images has been traversed, I want to display some output in the log. However, React immediately jumps to the "Then" block for the console output, which of course is then NULL. What am I doing wrong ?

```
const uploadImg = async () => {

setUploadIsDone(false);

if (file.length) {
  asyncFuncUploadToMongoDb().then((data) => {
    console.log(data); // Is called immediately 
    setProgress(0);
    setUploadIsDone(true);
  });
 }
};



const asyncFuncUploadToMongoDb = async () => {
const storage = getStorage();

return Promise.all(
  file.map((f) => {
    const articelImagesRef = ref(
      storage,
      "articelImg/" + new Date() + ".jpg"
    );
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(articelImagesRef, f);

    uploadTask.on(
      "state_changed",
      (snapshot) => {
        const progress =
          (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        setProgress(progress);
        // eslint-disable-next-line default-case
        switch (snapshot.state) {
          case "paused":
            console.log("Upload is paused");
            break;
          case "running":
            console.log("Upload is running");
            break;
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      () => {
        getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
          setImgUrl([...imgUrl, downloadURL]);
        });
      }
    );
   })
  );
 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `file.map` method, you are not returning any promise.

You should return each promise from the `map` method, in order to handle all of them with `Promise.all`.

---

Since you have a listener callback (and not a promise for your task), you could create and return a brand new promise to handle each map finish.

*Simple example based on your code (see comments)*

```
return Promise.all(
  file.map((f) => {
    // Create and return a new Promise for each file
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const articelImagesRef = ref(
        storage,
        "articelImg/" + new Date() + ".jpg"
      );
      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(articelImagesRef, f);

      uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        (snapshot) => {
          const progress =
            (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
          setProgress(progress);
          // eslint-disable-next-line default-case
          switch (snapshot.state) {
            case "paused":
              console.log("Upload is paused");
              break;
            case "running":
              console.log("Upload is running");
              break;
          }
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
          // Reject the promise when fail
          reject(error);
        },
        () => {
          getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
            setImgUrl([...imgUrl, downloadURL]);

            // Resolve the promise when ready
            resolve(downloadUrl); 
          }).catch(error => {
            // Reject the promise getting download url fail
            reject(error);
          });
        }
      );
    });
  })
);
```

Comment: @Captai-N, important edit! I've updated the post, also covering the case when `getDownloadUrl` fails using `catch` and `reject()`.
Otherwise, when that fails, the promise never resolves itself. Make sure to cover that case too for safety :) (in a promise always be sure that every possibile case ends with `resolve` or `reject` to avoid suspension)